# Why was my comment flag declined?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags

[C languages word weight distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839750/c-laguages-word-weight-distinct-can-you-help-me-c-programming)

It's a bad question. Anyway, I flagged the first comment with the custom reason, "Should be editted into question", and it was almost immediately declined. Yet, another user left a comment saying basically the same thing, so why was my flag declined?

Comment: Because it should have been a comment, not a flag, just like the other user did.

Comment: That is not an activity where flagging is valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Custom flags are for issues that require moderator intervention.  They should only be used if you cannot accomplish something through other regular means.  They will be declined if it is possible in other ways.  Often, you'll see this rejection message

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

In this situation, two perfectly viable options that you can accomplish on your own are:

- leave a comment like the other user
- make (or suggest) the edit yourself

After the post is edited to include that code, you could use a regular comment flag for "obsolete," which might be approved.

---

[Martijn comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300858/why-was-my-comment-flag-declined/300859?noredirect=1#comment229234_300859) that he was the mod who declined this specific flag "because it did not require a moderator to make that edit."

Comment: Ah, do custom comment flags get reviewed by mods only?

Comment: Yes all custom flags (as well as some other types) go to the mods.  Although I think comment flags of any kind still go to mods too.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that custom question answer flags and rude/spam flags were the only ones that went directly to mods. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I declined the flag, because it did not require a moderator to make that edit.