# If I flag a comment, and the comment is deleted, does my flag automatically get marked unhelpful?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags

I'll make this clear up front: The question I care about most is "Why was this flag declined?" However, while trying to ask this question, my ignorance of how Meta works and how Stack Overflow itself works are being exposed. Which means I have ancillary questions.

I can no longer find the comment to which this flag refers:

[image: Declined flag on comment that no longer exists]

Was the comment deleted? If so, was it deleted by a mod? If so, did the mod mark my flag as unhelpful? If so, why?

Seems like I am marking flags as "rude or abusive", mods are deleting them, and then marking my flags as declined. Perhaps this is to prevent harming the comment author? If so, that seems like the wrong thing to do.

The image below makes it look like the post was deleted, but in my flag history, I have this link:

[Download multiple pages concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491993/download-multiple-pages-concurrently/43831541#43831541)

Apparently, this means the comment was deleted. If the comment was deleted, why was my flag declined? Shouldn't my flag just disappear?

Comment: Comments can be deleted because they are no longer needed, but the mods still disagree with your "rude or abusive" view.

Comment: The problem with that is I no longer have the evidence needed for my defense.

Comment: Considering your last few questions, it seems you are really getting into flagging comments either unkind or rude.

Comment: No defense is needed. Just move on.

Comment: If you really want to prepare a case for a court of law (or this site), then take an image of the comment *before* flagging it, but I'm sure that you have more useful and productive things to do with your time

Comment: I believe rude/abusive flags persist for a mod to review even if the comment is deleted, so the mod can evaluate if there is need to take any action regarding the author of the flagged comment. So deletion wouldn't mark the flag as "automatically helpful".

Comment: The [post itself was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43831541/1038015), you need 10K rep to see deleted posts. That's why for you the link goes to the question but for 10K users it does show the deleted post.

Comment: The link posts to the specific comment on the specific answer, but that answer was deleted. **The question itself was not deleted**, so the link still works (shows you the question, but not the answer because it was deleted and as Robert mentioned you need to be >= 10k rep to see deleted posts).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is everyone going to avoid the actual question? Why was the flag declined?

Comment: One of my previous comments answers your latest edit to the question about the comment being deleted and your flag having to be reviewed.

Comment: @DavidCullen only the mod who declined it could answer that.

Comment: Nobody is "avoiding" the question. You are making multiple questions. And the "why was the flag denied part" can only be answered by the moderator than handled your flag.

Comment: @DavidCullen: if we on meta gave careful attention to each and every disputed flag on this site, we'd not have enough time to answer questions, work, sleep, or live our lives. I understand your point, but this is mainly about a difference of opinion.

Comment: @yivi I have used the "unfriendly or unkind" flag 9 times in the past 7 months. I have used the "rude or abuseive" twice in the past 5 months. Is that a lot? It doesn't seem like it. But is any of this relevant to the question? Not in my opinion.

Comment: As a note, if it wasn't mentioned before, mods can see deleted comments, in the case someone would like to ask why a comment was deleted but the flag declined another mod could add that comment text to the question, if they see that as necessary. They are technically able to do so.

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately, there were several problems. Firstly, the question I wanted to ask was a duplicate: [Why was my comment flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300858/why-was-my-comment-flag-declined). So I asked another question about which I was curious and included the query about my specific flag. When the mod arrived on the scene, he pointed out that I had flagged an answer. So despite my good intentions, everything that could have gone wrong went wrong. Even so, I did finally get the answer to my question. And I learned a lot about Stack Overflow today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: that specific flag was not a comment flag, you flagged the answer.

The answer mostly consists of copied code; it starts with “*I  get help from some expert today, as he post the python 2.X code for referrence.* followed by a pastebin link, code, and some more text. On the face of it such posts are not rude or offensive; the answerer clearly meant to answer the question, just in a misguided way.

So I declined the flag. I then deleted the answer because it was basically plagiarising someone else’s work.

Only *then* did I see that the original code in the Pastebin used a rather off colour URL link placeholder text. That was probably what caused you to flag the post as rude in the first place.

However, a single rude word, in code in what is otherwise a reasonable attempt at answering doesn’t warrant deletion of the post, let alone flagging as rude or offensive. In such cases the community can *edit* the post and replace that one rude reference, without moderator intervention or punitive results on the account that posted the answer.

The code was copied here and you could argue that altering it would be inappropriate as it should have been a quote, but luckily we don’t have to consider that issue here as it was much better just deleted for plagiarism reasons.

In cases like these where the inappropriate references were introduced by the author themselves, we *can* just clear the flags from the post (and you end up with a “disputed” flag), and just do what we want the community to do on their own: edit the post.

In future, keep the rude or offensive flag for posts where the post is being rude directly to someone (the question asker, the community, or someone or some group in general).  Using juvenile code references are not aimed at anyone in particular. Also see the [central FAQ on how to use the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: Thank you, sir. Because I can't see the deleted answer, I couldn't remember what I flagged. And yes, I flagged the answer because it contained a curse word. However, the real cause of the problem may still exist. The hint for the flag says this: "A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse." I consider myself a reasonable person and I found the content inappropriate. I was unaware of information that would have helped me make a better decision. And I've been knocking around this site for a while. So if I'm having this problem, others may also have it.

Comment: Specifically, I was unaware that "rude" means "rude directly to someone". However, another problem I faced was that because the answer was deleted, I could no longer see it. So I made the mistake because I didn't understand the definition of rude and I didn't understand why it was a mistake because I couldn't see it anymore and when I came to Meta, I did almost all of the wrong things. I say almost all, because I'm sure that simply due to lack of imagination on my part, I omitted some wrong things that I could have included.

Comment: @DavidCullen see the [help centre information on the flagging privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), which links to [this usage guide on how to use the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035). It contains: *If an **otherwise valid** post contains vulgar words as an expression of frustration, edit the bad part out instead of flagging the entire post as rude or abusive.*

Comment: Bruce Schneier said [If you ask amateurs to act as front-line security personnel, you shouldn't be surprised when you get amateur security.](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2007/11/the_war_on_the.html). I did everything wrong. I admit that. However, I was motivated to do the things I did by [Stack Overflow Isn't Very Welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). When I read that post, I knew it was a bad idea.

Comment: I think you are being way, way too hard on yourself here. You at least came forward to try and learn from the feedback received. Read the info you have been given, and move forward.

Comment: However, I wasn't directly affected until today. When I tried to find out why, I learned a lot of things that some folks would argue I should have already known.

Comment: I'm less worried about myself than I am about all of the other people trying to make the site better by using the flags but making the same mistakes. How many of those people will just give up rather than endure the "kindness" I received today?

Answer (score 8):

If we delete a flagged post or comment then the flag is marked as helpful.

However, if you chose an inappropriate flag, e.g. rude/abusive, for something that wasn't but still needed to be deleted then there's a good chance that your flag would be declined yet the post or comment would still get deleted.

The red flags - spam and rude/abusive - should be reserved for things that are truly that. Validating this flags can potentially bring serious consequences down on the person whose posts are being flagged and some of these consequences are automatic - e.g. spam blocks. So inappropriate flagging could lead to an otherwise blameless user being blocked from using the site.

Please use the most appropriate flag for each situation. If you think that the standard flags don't cover the situation then use an other flag to explain in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I asked this question was that originally, I just wanted to know why my flag was declined. You might think I'm wasting my time, but because my comment flag was declined, I'm not allowed to use the question flags. So this whole thing looks like a waste of time to you, but it is very important to me because I want to learn what I'm doing wrong so I don't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I did not know that flagging a comment as "rude or abusive" had negative consequences for the comment author. Knowing that means I'll never use that flag again.

Comment: @DavidCullen that's a bit of an overreaction. If you see something that's rude please use the rude/abusive flag. In those cases we probably do want the consequences to apply to that user.

Comment: Without a more clear explanation from Stack Overflow about the definition of "Rude or Abusive" I'm not going to do any better with my flags. I've only used that flag twice, and both times I apparently got it wrong. And now I find out that getting it wrong might trigger an automatic system that harms another user. Not worth it.

Comment: @DavidCullen There's no automatic system. There's an auto flag raised if a user has 3+ comments marked as harassment or unfriendly in a week but the mods still choose whether to act on that auto flag or not. There's nothing to fear. Please, flag.